# Using an older python in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've 2 versions of python installed, version 3.6 and 2.7.13, I installed the second later
I'm having a problem when I tried to use virtual environment to work on stuff using 2.7 and it doesn't seem to work
I tried...

```
$ virtualenv -p python2 myenv
```

but it's not working , i tried even changing it into python 2.7 and 2.7.1 but it's not working and says that the path doesn't exist

am i missing something here?
thanks,

Comment: you also likely have virtualenv installed in the python3 environment so it will use that as default. If you want python2 preferred see if you can `pip2 install virtualenv` to use a python2 based installation. Otherwise the answers below should suffice in creating a one-off python2 venv

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `python2` exists as a path by doing:

```
which python2
```

That should come up with something like `/usr/bin/python2` if it doesn't then you aren't giving `virtualenv` a valid alias/location for `python`

It's likely your versions of python will exist in `/usr/bin/<python>` try finding the path to the existing version and use that whole path. E.g:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 py27
```

It's also likely that python2.7 could be installed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner.

```
virtualenv myenv -p `which python2.7`
```

Obviously assuming that `which python2.7` command returns a valid alias on your system.